# Facebook login permission - com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid permission

Tags: android, android-facebook

I'm using `Facebook SDK 3.6.0`.
Al Login I ask for different READ permissions: `"basic_info", "email",  "user_birthday", "friends_birthday"` and some others.
I have 2 apps created on Facebook - seems to be identical (both are public, both have the same configuration), but with one of it I cannot perform Login, each time I receive the following errors:

a. when I press on the "Log in with Facebook" button

```
 06-04 00:40:35.088: INFO/BufferQueue(136): [com.droid.tep.apps.FBStatistics/com.facebook.LoginActivity](this:0x41a8fa08,api:1) new GraphicBuffer needed
06-04 00:40:35.111: WARN/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14766): Exception during service
        com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: The proxied app is not already installed.
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:86)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:165)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:151)
        at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
        at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:59)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:31)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:312)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:142)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:98)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:228)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:415)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:170)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:18)
        at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
        at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:345)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:56)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

b. when I press on the OK buttom from the Fb permission dialog:

```
06-04 00:37:25.693: VERBOSE/ActivityManager(490): Broadcast: Intent { act=com.facebook.common.hardware.NetworkActivityBroadcastManager.NETWORKING_ACTIVE flg=0x10 (has extras) } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=ProcessRecord{41dfde50 14766:com.facebook.katana/u0a10079}
06-04 00:37:25.713: WARN/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14766): Exception during service
        com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid permission: friends_birthday
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:86)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:165)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:151)
        at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
        at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:59)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:31)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:312)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:142)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:98)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:228)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:415)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:170)
        at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:18)
        at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
        at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:345)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:56)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-04 00:37:25.723: WARN/fb4a(:<default>):GDPDialog(14766): Failed to send
        com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:639)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation.c(BlueServiceOperation.java:47)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.BlueServiceOperation$2.run(BlueServiceOperation.java:604)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 00:37:25.738: DEBUG/BufferQueue(136): [Facebook](this:0x417d3e28,api:1) cancelBuffer: slot=1
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to the problem you have stated? Facing exactly similar issue.

Comment: No, I've never got the chance to get this work. Fortunately I could use the first app created (which, strange, is exactly like the one which is causing me problems). If you find a solution, please post it here also. Thanks.